# Error connecting to MariaDB from Linux Environment:: ImportError: libmariadb.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: sqlalchemy, mariadb

## ImportError: libmariadb.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mariadb_connector.py", line 14, in <module>
    engine = create_engine(CONNECTION_STRING)
  File "<string>", line 2, in create_engine
  File "/home/projadmin/Downloads/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/deprecations.py", line 309, in warned
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/projadmin/Downloads/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py", line 560, in create_engine
    dbapi = dialect_cls.dbapi(**dbapi_args)
  File "/home/projadmin/Downloads/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/mariadbconnector.py", line 106, in dbapi
    return __import__("mariadb")
  File "/home/projadmin/Downloads/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mariadb/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from ._mariadb import (
ImportError: libmariadb.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: You need to install the mariadb v3 client libs for your distro, possibly `libmariadb3`

Comment: Hi Bib, thanks for your response. Understood, we have to install all the mariadb client libs. I have already copied the libraries from Connector/C package to /usr/local/lib.

Can you pls let me know what else needs to be added ?

Comment: @Bib, so I have checked `libmariadb3`, but it isn't available for RHEL7;
[admin@server ~]$ **yum install libmariadb3**
Loaded plugins: enabled_repos_upload, langpacks, package_upload, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager      
No package libmariadb3 available.
Error: Nothing to do
Uploading Enabled Repositories Report
Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, subscription-manager

Comment: I don't have a system to check, but given how broken the numbering system is, the version number may be something like 10.3, it's the .3 at the end (I think), which says they are v3. Look at the RH Software collections v3.3 to v3.6. Read the docs carefully, and backup what's there, since you will break things.

Comment: ok, thank you appreciate your support @Bib I will go through the docs once.

Comment: Hi @Bib,

I managed to *solve the issue by using just another SQL - driver* **(pymysql)** to connect to Maria DB.

Old `CONNECTION_STRING = 'mariadb+mariadbconnector' + '://{}:{}@{}:{}/{}'.format(USERNAME, quote(PASSWORD), HOST, str(PORT), DB_NAME)`

Modified to;
New `CONNECTION_STRING = 'mariadb+pymysql' + '://{}:{}@{}:{}/{}'.format(USERNAME, quote(PASSWORD), HOST, str(PORT), DB_NAME)`
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to *solve the issue by using just another SQL - driver* **(pymysql)** to connect to Maria DB.

Old

```
CONNECTION_STRING = 'mariadb+mariadbconnector' + '://{}:{}@{}:{}/{}'.format(USERNAME, quote(PASSWORD), HOST, str(PORT), DB_NAME)
```

Modified to;
New

```
CONNECTION_STRING = 'mariadb+pymysql' + '://{}:{}@{}:{}/{}'.format(USERNAME, quote(PASSWORD), HOST, str(PORT), DB_NAME)
```

Thanks